# Intersection of a hypersurface with a projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I don't understand the argument in the proof of Corollary 3.15 (This is from Harris). In particular, how exactly is Corollary 3.14 applied?

[image]

Comment: Seriously? 10k reputation and you post a *photograph*?

Comment: @5xum: What is wrong with posting a photo?

Comment: @5xum: In your "expert" opinion i should have replicated the entire text of the book relevant to my question?

Comment: If the question can be typed, then it should be typed. That way, users can find it more easily (using either internal search or Google). And yes, in my oppinion, you should at least type down the question and the part of the proof that is confusing you. That's how 99% of the people are doing it...

Comment: I wouldn't argue that there are better ways of asking the question. But this does not justify your willingness to attack my question. All the more when it seems that algebraic geometry is not your favorite subject.

Comment: I am attacking this question because it is not up to site standards, thus in my opinion deserves a downvote. Anyway, you don't have to change a thing if you don't want to. My advice is that you change it if you want people to take the question seriously.

Comment: I agree with 5xum. A photograph from someone who knows how to type is an indication of laziness, and selfishness. No one else searching for a similar problem will likely find this question.

Comment: @Jonny: But everyone interested in Corollary 3.15 of Harris will (or in the intersection of a projective variety with a hypersurface). By the way, you should be very careful with the denominations you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional piece of information which is missing (but surely is not hard to deduce) is

> Every two points in a projective space can be distinguished by a  degree $d$ form, for $d \geq 1$. That is, whenever given $d \geq 1$ and two points $P_1, P_2 \in \mathbb{P}^n$, there is a form $G$ of degree $d$ such that $G(P_1)=0$ and $G(P_2)\neq 0$.

If $P_1, P_2$ are two distinct points in $X$, choose $G$ of degree $d$ such that $G(P_1)=0$ and $G(P_2)\neq 0$. Then $(G/F)(P_2)=0$ and $(G/F)(P_2)\neq 0$, contradiction with $G/F$ being constant on $X$.

Comment: Why can a regular function on $X$ here be defined globally as $G/F$? Don't we have just a local representation of a regular function, and then this argument fails as then $G/F$ might not be the same regular function at a different point. Sorry, I am confused!

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac I am prescribing one particular regular function on $X$, and  it is done by $P \mapsto G(P)/F(P)$. The assumption $(X \cap V(F)=)X \cap Y=\emptyset$ says that $F(P)\neq 0$ whenever $P \in X$, so the function is well-defined at every point, so it is a complete prescription of a global regular function on $X$. And sure, there can potentially be some regular functions on $X$ not admitting such global description, but we don't need to care about those for this argument.